# How to send a file to download as response in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have requirement that the HTML page needs to converted to PDF file and sending PDF as response to the api call in node. For that i am using wkhtmltopdf package to convert HTML to PDF.

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var http= require("http");
var app = express();
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
var fs = require('fs');
var res1 = fs.createWriteStream('out2.pdf');


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});


app.get('/getPDF',function(req, res){
    wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>').pipe(res1);
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.send(res1);

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

But it is creating out2.pdf in the project folder. but i am unable to get the out2.pdf as downloadable file in the browser instead i am getting below error

**Error**

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:191:12)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:238:5)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:563:20)
```

any idea how to achieve my requirement

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
app.get('/getPDF',function(req, res){
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
  wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>').pipe(res1).pipe(res);
});
```

Pipe the result of `wkhtmltopdf` to `response` stream.